# how to change a string value to float number

Tags: javascript

```
var str = '2.20';
```

is there any parsing method or whatever, which can change it into integer.

```
var floatNum = 1.20;
floatNum += str ;
```

so as a result i want

```
console.log(floatNum) => 3.40
// not 3.4
```

how to make it happen ?

Comment: [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: ... "not 3.4" because you are somehow convinced that is different from "3.40"?

Comment: @Andreas this will return 3.4 not 3.40  i want `3.40` due to some display purpose.

Comment: @Jongware no, I am not convinced with 3.4. i want `3.40` only

Comment: Then you are converting for the wrong reasons. Floating numbers do not have leading or following zeroes. They are *numbers*.

Comment: I got the answer, and solved by `varFloat.toFixed(2);`  to get decimal zero.

Comment: may i know any reason for downvote ?

Comment: I'm gonna take a stab here, but "no, I am not convinced with 3.4. i want 3.40 only" is not very helpful. @Jongware is right, mathematically there is no difference. If you are going to do operations on it, then don't use `toFixed`, only use it for display purposes (right before displaying the number!). Otherwise its a waste of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)** for parsing string to convert it to float and **[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** for specifying fractional part length

```js
var floatNum = 1.20,
  str = '2.20';
floatNum += parseFloat(str, 10);

console.log(floatNum.toFixed(2))
```

Comment: And use `toFixed` to get `3.40` back and not the `3.4`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `parseFloat()` function to convert the string to a floating point no.:

```
floatNum += parseFloat(str);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

To output the floating point no. with a fixed no. of decimal places, use `toFixed()` (thanks to user somethinghere for mentioning this).

```
console.log(floatNum.toFixed(2));
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: And use `toFixed` to get `3.40` back and not the `3.4`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "2.20";
var float = 3.40;

var result = float + parseFloat(str);
```

Comment: And use `toFixed` to get `3.40` back and not the `3.4`